# Azure CD pipeline can't find build artifacts

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, build-pipeline

Below is Azure error log from the Azure release pipeline.

```
2020-07-24T05:17:13.7712974Z ##[section]Starting: Deploy Azure App Service
2020-07-24T05:17:14.0464143Z ==============================================================================
2020-07-24T05:17:14.0465719Z Task         : Azure App Service deploy
2020-07-24T05:17:14.0469391Z Description  : Deploy to Azure App Service a web, mobile, or API app using Docker, Java, .NET, .NET Core, Node.js, PHP, Python, or Ruby
2020-07-24T05:17:14.0469849Z Version      : 3.163.5
2020-07-24T05:17:14.0470410Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2020-07-24T05:17:14.0470921Z Help         : https://aka.ms/azureappservicetroubleshooting
2020-07-24T05:17:14.0471274Z =============================================================================
2020-07-24T05:17:16.0650643Z Got connection details for Azure App Service:'XXXXX'
2020-07-24T05:17:17.6576087Z (node:764) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
**2020-07-24T05:17:17.6627737Z ##[error]Error: No package found with specified pattern: D:\a\r1\a\Drop<br/>Check if the package mentioned in the task is published as an artifact in the build or a previous stage and downloaded in the current job.**
2020-07-24T05:17:22.9168975Z Successfully added release annotation to the Application Insight : XXXXX
2020-07-24T05:17:24.8686063Z Successfully updated deployment History at https://XXXXX.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/deployments/231595567842919
2020-07-24T05:17:24.8933576Z ##[section]Finishing: Deploy Azure App Service
```

P.S. I have checked build pipeline, I can download build Artificats, but it displays below warning.

### [warning]Directory 'D:\a\1\a' is empty. Nothing will be added to build artifact 'drop'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you meant you have solved the build artifact empty issue, but the release pipeline still had issue in `Azure App Service deploy` task.

As the error mentioned, there is "No package found with specified pattern: D:\a\r1\a\Drop", you need to check how you define the **package**, try format `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/**/*.zip` instead of `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\Drop`.

Answer (score 0):

As task "Publish Build Artifact" publish artifact from $(build.artifactstagingdirectory), so we need add a task "Copy files" to copy your files ** from $(system.defaultworkingdirectory) to $(build.artifactstagingdirectory) **. which copied my build to stagingdirectory.

Comment: Thanks cece Dong for review, but this is one of the problem is solved, but still entire issue is not solved.

Comment: If you have other issues, you could open new tickets.

Comment: No, issue is same as it can't find build artifacts.

Comment: I'm a little confused that what's the meaning of this answer if the issue is not solved? How did you define the artifact in the release pipeline? And how did you define the `Deploy Azure App Service` task? Could you elaborate your issue?